# google app engine's ndb: get an entity's id

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

This looks simple, but I just didn't find how to get an entity's id from Google App Engine's ndb.

```
class Message(ndb.Model):
    name: ndb.StringProperty()
    ...
```

Create a message object:

```
message = Message(id=someId)
message.name = someName
message.put()
```

Later when I retrieve the entity:

```
message = Message.query(Message.name==someName).fetch(1)
```

Now how do I get the message's id? Thanks.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can get the **id** with several ways provided you have the **key**.

**Example** with `fetch` or `get`:

```
message = Message.query(Message.name==someName).fetch(1)[0]
message_id = message.key.id()

message = Message.query(Message.name==someName).get()
message_id = message.key.id()
```

---

If you **don't need** the entity but **only the id** then you can save resources by getting only the key.

```
message_key = Message.query(Message.name==someName).fetch(1, keys_only=True)[0]
message_id = message_key.id()

message_key = Message.query(Message.name==someName).get(keys_only=True)
message_id = message_key.id()
```

---

Keep in mind that you can get the key after a **put** as well:

```
message_key = message.put()
message_id = message_key.id()
```

---

From [Key Class NDB](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/keyclass?hl=id#Key_id)

Comment: or after a put : message_id = message.put().id()

Comment: @voscausa yes but only on put because put() returns the Key instance

Answer (score 1):

Try using get() to for a single instance

```
message = Message.query(Message.name==someName).get()
message.key.id()
```

fetch() returns a list object so your code will need to be roughly this:

```
messages = Message.query(Message.name==someName).fetch(1)
message = messages[0]
message.key.id()
```

Comment: Thanks. You can as well do: `message = Message.query(Message.name==someName).fetch(1)[0]`